# Best Practice for using Stored Procedures in asp.net for inserting Data

Tags: asp.net, database, stored-procedures

I was wondering if anyone can give me a link on following a best practice pattern for inserting data in a SQL db using stored procedures. I mean, what procedures should we take to ensure validated data to be passed through stored procedures.

Comment: I don't understand your question. The obvious answer is, "validate the data before you use it", but that's too obvious to be what you meant. Please clarify.

Comment: Act like the data has not been validated when you get it?

Comment: NO I am validating Data, for size and DataType. But what if some hacker tries to add some javascript code or SQL Code. How can I trap those things?

Moreover, is it ok if I just use this statement for entering parameters

cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", TxtID.Text.ToString());

I just wanted to know if there is a good practice pattern for these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different ways to do this depending on if you are using an ORM or using direct database access.  One thing is you should use the SqlParameter object to create SP parameters.  There are a wide variety of ways to create a SqlParameter with various options but the simplest form is

```
 SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[1];
 prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@userid", "Bob");
```

Comment: But how can I trap javscript or SQL code if they passes it into some textbox?

For example, I am allowing user to write an email message and I am saving that message too in db before sending email. But I don't want users/hackers to write a fully functional code in SQL to hack my site or corrupt the data. Even though I am using Sql parameters, but is it secure?

Comment: If you use parameters, then the hackers cannot perform a SQL injection.

Comment: So thats what I am asking, that the statement which Mr. Cody C has given is enough for me, then or do I need to do some other things too?

Comment: you should always do basic validation on the user input but the parameters will protect you against the standard SQL Injection attacks.  However as a general rule, all data should be validated on the client and server end before sending it to the database.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you embed any logic for validation at a layer *above* the stored procedure implementation. In this way you can have much more flexibility in your implementation and exposure. A simple example is that you can reuse a validation library across multiple projects. Most ORM libraries support validation in its simplest form by verifying appropriate type assignment at compile time.

I would also recommend that you implement your transactional logic in a layer *above* the stored procedures.

Comment: I really, really dig SubSonic [http://subsonicproject.com/Download]. I had a pleasant experience w/ 2.2 but have yet to use the newly released 3.0.